# Count number of instances of a task that took longer than expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in Excel VBA that has an input of a set of tasks, and how long each task took. There are multiple instances of each task.

I want to count how many instances of each task were overdue. The amount of time until it is overdue will depend on the task, so I added an input box so users can enter this for each task. The macro should then check, for each task, how many instances took longer than this input.

So for example, if there are 3 instances of Task 1, which took 2 days, 3 days, and 4 days respectively, and I input the expected time as 2 days, this should return that 2 instances of the task were overdue.

My code is outputting numbers that when checked manually are wrong - generally much lower than the actual.

I've tried making sure everything is an integer in case that was the issue, but it didn't change anything.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim AshRow As Integer
Dim EweRow As Integer
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim all As Range
Dim allRows As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim origTasks As Range
'Previously tried Dim expTime As Variant
Dim expTime As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim task As String

EweRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.count

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastCell = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set all = Range("A1", Range("A" & lastCell))
End With

    Set origTasks = Worksheets("Page1_1").Range("A2", "A" & EweRow)

    'For each task, cycle through each row of the original report and note anything over the given value

    Set allRows = Range("A2", Range("A" & lastCell))

    For Each r In allRows.Cells
        count = 0
        task = r.Value
        expTime = InputBox("Please enter the expected time for the task: " & task)
        'Check this is an integer and make it one if not
        If Not IsNumeric(expTime) Then
            expTime = CInt(expTime)
        End If

        For Each n In origTasks.Cells
            If n.Value = task Then
                m = n.Offset(0, 1).Value
                'Check value is an integer
                If Not IsNumeric(m) Then
                    m = CInt(m)
                End If

                If m > expTime Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    r.Offset(0, 4).Value = count  
    Next r

    'Format
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the times in *whole* days only (2 days, 3 days, etc.)?

Comment: There is no `End With` in the end (before `End Sub`)

Comment: ^ More importantly, the `With` is never being referenced, you need to add periods before `Cells`, `Rows`,`Range`.

Comment: How does your code even compile? Looking at that missing `End With`?

Comment: Sorry, messed up trying to cut out the code that wasn't relevant! I'll fix that now. And yes, the times are in whole days only.

Comment: I could see using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to get rid of your inner `For` loop.